# Cannot assign to view controller's property after instantiating from storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm instantiating a view controller from the storyboard with this code:

```
CalloutViewController *calloutVC = (CalloutViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CalloutViewController"];
```

and trying to assign to it's property nameLabel, declared here in its header:

```
@interface CalloutViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
...
@end
```

using

```
calloutVC.nameLabel.text = @"test";
```

However, after the assignment, the property is still nil.

Comment: In what method are you trying to set the label's text? And what is nil? The text or nameLabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `IBOutlet` is not loaded yet. You need to create a `NSString` property and assign your value to it. And in your `CalloutViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` assign the value to your `IBOutlet`.

Like:

```
@interface CalloutViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *nameValue;
...
@end
```

And in your `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.nameLabel.text = self.nameValue;
   ...
}
```

And assign the property like:

```
calloutVC.nameValue = @"test";
```

Comment: Thanks... you saved me a ton of time!! Do you know why doing the same thing with a non-IBOutlet UILabel wouldn't work? e.g., I just had

Comment: @michael: Did you allocated that label before using ?

Comment: No, that was the problem! Ridiculously obvious in retrospect but I just wasn't seeing it. I just passed a dictionary in and then assigned everything in viewDidLoad. Thanks again!